# How to call "javaws -uninstall" in C# program?

Tags: c#, shell, command-line-arguments

I need to create a tool which would clear java cache on our system and for that i need to call "javaws -uninstall' command that can be executed in CMD in my program.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to run commands from a command line.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "javaws";
startInfo.Arguments = "uninstall";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

While using just `Process.Start()` is shorter, creating a `ProcessStartInfo` instance gives you better control over the console. So if you do not want to show the CLI windows, for instance, use this with appropriate settings.

Comment: This seems to be not working,instead of deleting the cache,it is downloading the same,i tried with process also and it isnt working.

Comment: And are you sure that is only "javaws -uninstall" and nothing more?

Comment: yes,if i write this command "javaws -uninstall" ,it will delete java cache from the system and while checking only "javaws" in cmd,it is shown that "uninstall" is a control option,so will it affect anything?

Comment: Works for me. You can alternatively try out `javaws -clearcache` or if you have only few applications then use option `java -uninstall <jnlp-file>`

Answer (score 1):

Start the process using:

```
Process.Start("javaws", "uninstall")
```

More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This makes the assumption that `javaws` is in your [PATH variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). You may have to use the absolute path